Help me to understand the input/output strides, number of transforms and input/output distance of 2D/3D data to perform DFT with oneAPI MLK libs
The computed excitation vectors of each basis function $m$ at level $\ell$ are just the samples on the sphere represented as $\zeta_m^\ell(\phi_i,\theta_j)$.
These samples are interpolated to get samples $\zeta_m^{\ell-1}(\phi_\tilde{i},\theta_\tilde{j})$ at level $\ell-1$
Fast Spherical Filter is one of the algorithm that starts the interpolation process by taking Fourier transform of samples $\zeta_m^\ell(\phi_i,\theta_j)$ in $\phi$ direction at first and continues$\dots$
Right now I perform this interpolation for each basis which is very slow.
Instead, I was thinking whether

Is it possible to take the Fourier Transform of samples of all the basis at once like?

$$\mathrm{FT}\left[\zeta_{m=0}^\ell(\phi_i,\theta_j),\,\zeta_{m=1}^\ell(\phi_i,\theta_j),\dots,\,\zeta_{m=\mathrm{M-1}}^\ell(\phi_i,\theta_j)\right]$$

How do I setup the input/output strides, number of transforms, input/output distance etc?

I am using Intel oneAPI MKL libraries to compute the forward and backward Fourier transform.

Further, what are number of transforms and in the current context $\mathrm{M}$ be number of transforms and the distance is $\mathrm{M}ij$?
